# How to put List of Table and List of Algorithm in the same page

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a very short List of Algorithm (LoA), therefore to save pages, I want to put the LoA in the same page as the List of Table (LoT). Currently, my output looks like the following picture.

[image: LoT and LoA on separate pages]

I tried to use \usepackage{tocloft} but to no avail. Please help me how to put the LoT and LoA on the same page. The following is the packages that I am using (simplified).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
              headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
              numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt} %without space utk jilid

%to get rid of empty page between chapter:
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ccicons} 
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack} % ignore warnings about deprecated KOMA-Script
\usepackage[printonlyused,smaller,withpage]{acronym}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage[floatperchapter,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing,linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tocloft} %to combine list of table and algorithms
\usepackage{xcolor}
\areaset{16cm}{28.1cm}%{26.1cm} %def 17, 27.1 %remove this to use default type

\input{mysettings}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

\end{document}
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\listoftables
    
{\let\cleardoublepage\relax \listofalgorithms }
```

to prevent the chapter List of Algorithm issuing a new page.

[image: a]

Comment: ah perfect, it works! thank you very much!

Comment: For me, I had to replace `\cleardoublepage` there with `clearpage` with the `scrreprt` document class.